# Edit PDF documents in Delphi

Tags: delphi, pdf, editor, components

We have a requirement to add the ability to edit PDF documents witin a Delphi application.

I.e. given a PDF document, open it and generate a form with edit boxes on it which the user can use to update the PDF document.

Can anyone suggest a third part component that would provide this functionality or suggest some way of achieving this.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a job for Torry's Delphi pages?  Here's a list on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PDF_software .  And there are several Delphi wrappers for Gnu PDF.  As well as TQPDF: http://delphi.about.com/od/toppicks/a/tqpdf.htm

Comment: @paulsm4 This is a good option: add it below as an Answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use [QuickPDF](http://www.quickpdflibrary.com/).  Well documented, lots of examples, good support.  However updating text in a PDF is an art, not a science, and unless you have full control over the producer of the PDF you may find it hard to do in the general case.  For example: I have seen PDFs where text is formed from individual characters, each inserted at a specific location, so hard to edit as words; and of course in some PDFs the 'text' is actually an image of text, requiring OCR before you can edit it.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Gnostice PDFtoolkit](http://www.gnostice.com/nl_article.asp?id=250&t=Introduction_to_PDFtoolkit_VCL).

DISCLAIMER: I work for Gnostice.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Amyuni PDF Creator ActiveX](http://www.amyuni.com/en/developer/pdfcreatoractivex/), it is supported in 32 bit and 64 bit applications, you may find it useful now that [Delphi has a 64 compiler](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi/64-bit).

*Usual disclaimer applies*